# How do I add text to the side of an image in HTML

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to add text to the side of an image (more of an oval) in HTML, does anyone know how?

[image: Picture to add text]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you put text inside a  element it will be on the same line (inline).

```
<div> 
    <img src="img.png" />
    <span>your text here</span>
<div>
```

If you'd like to center your text to the left, a simple CSS flex box solution would be:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

   span {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <Img src='' style='float:left' />
   <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```